# Invoke /system/bin/sdcard manually via terminal

Tags: sd-card, mount, terminal, command-line, services

I am trying to mount an EXT4 formatted SD card under Cyanogenmod 13.1 (Android 6.0.1).

So far, I have setup scripts to mount the card at `/mnt/ext_sdcard` during boot. My current understanding is that the "sdcard" service must then be invoked to create a FUSE mount pointing to the real mount point which will eventually lead the media scanner to the newly mounted disk.

Following some older [older documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+/jb-mr1-release/src/tech/storage/index.md) and forum threads lead me to this command in terminal:

```
service sdcard /system/bin/sdcard /mnt/ext_sdcard /mnt/test 1023 1023
    class late_start
```

When I run the command (as root of course), it fails with an exit status of `1` and no output/error messages.

My question: Am I doing something wrong, or is this command deprecated in 6.0.1 (the documents/forum thread seemed to relate to KitKat)? What is the correct syntax/arguments for using this command?

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting this command in an init.*.rc file? My understanding is you would have this in a init.extmount.rc for example. This requires extracting and repacking the boot.img.

Since I had nothing better to do, I created this: https://github.com/BenBaltz/mountext

Its a recovery flashable zip to install your script by unpacking the boot.img and repacking it with the modifications.

EDIT
Terminal commands

```
su -c mount -o bind /mnt/ext_sdcard /path/to/new/dir
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll check out your script. Also, yes I am using this command in the main init.rc file currently

Comment: I tried your command in init.mountext..rc and I got `service: Unknown command sdcard`. Then I tried `service call sdcard...` which returned `Service sdcard does not exist`.  Also I found two running instances of `sdcard` on my system and found they were invoked with `/system/bin/sdcard -u1023 -g1023 -U0 /mnt/media_rw/8005-91F9 8005-91F9`. Does this command vary between Android ROM's?

Comment: @Jake I don't see anything after 'I got'.

Comment: @Jake This is what the bootlogs said? You have to reboot for it to be run.

Comment: No, I ran it directly in terminal (as root). I'd rather run them in terminal until I'm sure they work rather than patching system files.

Comment: @Jake That's not possible. If you want to just have all the files in your regular sdcard a bind mount can be run in a live system. You could use mount -o bind /mnt/ext_sdcard /sdcard I do not know if you can create a bind mount to an empty dir, I am testing that now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52130/discussion-between-jake-and-ben-baltz).

Answer (score 0):

In Android 6+ [storage configuration](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config):

> Mounting of physical external storage volumes is handled by `vold`, which performs staging operations to prepare the media before exposing it to apps.
>   ...
>   The hard-coded FUSE services have been removed from device-specific `init.rc` files and are instead forked dynamically from `vold` when needed.

So the `sdcard` services defined in `*.rc` files are no more required, neither `storage_list.xml` is maintained inside `framework-res.apk`. Instead `vold` completely manages the storage devices defined with flag `voldmanaged=` in `fstab`. See more details in [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526).

In Android 9 FUSE support was completely removed from `sdcard` binary replaced with `sdcardfs`. `sdcardfs` can be mounted directly using `mount` command, so `sdcard` isn't necessarily required. However from Android 6 to 8 `sdcard` binary should mount an emulated filesystem if executed with proper arguments. You can see the failure log in `logcat`.

Also you can use a third party FUSE-based tool `bindfs` to achieve the same. See details in [How to bind mount a folder inside /sdcard with correct permissions?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217936/218526)