# External SD Card Mounted, Permissions granted, but still Inaccessible on LineageOS

Tags: sd-card, lineageos, amazon-kindle-fire

I know there's a ton of external SD card questions, but my case doesn't seem to line up with any of them, sorry if this has been asked before and I just couldn't find it.

I'm running LineageOS 14.1 on a Fire HD 10 Gen 7. When I insert my SD Card the system recognizes it, I go in and make sure that all the apps that need it have permission to access SD card storage, and I enabled Global Namespace in Magisk. But LineageOS *only* mounts it to `/mnt/media_rw/0000-0000` and there is no way to access it without going through the root directory.

Using a root browser I can see all of it's contents, but I can't access anything using any other apps. For example, I can see there's an mp4 file in the file browser, but if I open with VLC via the root browsers VLC immediately crashes. And if I try to go to the SD card via VLC, it isn't there, the only storage is Internal Memory.

All the other question articles I read were either concerning moving apps to the SD card, which I was able to do with Link2SD when creating an ext4 partition on the card, but the FAT32 partition was still inaccessible even by the apps on the ext4 partition which makes me think the issue isn't with the SD card (the SD card also works as intended on my PC), or were solved when they enabled permissions for the apps to access external storage, which I have done.

What do I need to do to make the SD Card accessible by apps other than my file browser?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/166557 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221122