# Can't read media files from mounted SD card partition

Tags: permissions, partitions, mount

I have a tablet that I flashed with a modded (rooted) system partition. A side effect of this system partition is that it killed my 20gb SD card partition that is the main storage for the device.

I was able to remount the partition by creating a directory, setting permissions, and mounting using the following commands:

```
$ mkdir /mnt/media_rw/sd2
$ chmod 777 /mnt/media_rw/sd2
$ mount -o rw /dev/block/blck27 /mnt/media_rw/sd2
```

**This works, but two problems occur:**

1. I cannot open media files, such as movies, or run an apk file and install apps. It just says **Cannot open this file.** I know there's nothing wrong with the files, as I can simply move them over to the small 5gb partition and read them just fine.
2. Less importantly (I created a separate post about this issue already) I'm unable to access the SD card storage on my PC via USB.

Regarding #1, it's an issue I really need to resolve, because otherwise I'd have to copy anything over to the small storage in order to watch movies, listen to music, or any other type of media file...

I'm not overly concerned with #2, but if you have some insight that would be great.

Comment: permissions are handled by [vold](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219743)

Comment: @alecxs Could you give me an example of how I would modify my mount command in order to straighten this out? This is very interesting actually, because I noticed in the **fstab** file in the old system partition, it includes the following flag `voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto,noemulatedsd` The problem is, I don't know how to mimic this particular set of properties using the mount command. It's also `vfat`, if that helps at all.

Comment: do it in fstab like discovered. or try init service /system/bin/sdcard (linked)

Comment: @alecxs I thought **fstab** was a part of the ROM, and it cannot be persistently modified? I figured I needed to create a script, and run it with init.d script support or something. My understanding was that if I changed **fstab**, it would just revert back to it's old self on reboot, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: yes, fstab should be modified in boot partition or vendor partition. from init.d script nothing works

Comment: @alecxs Yes, the fstab I found is in the vendor partition.. Hmm, I didn't realize that being in the vendor partition allows me to edit it. Wow that could simplify this drastically. I'll try that asap. Thanks!!